# How do I export contact data records?

Tags: export

I am attempting to export to contact data records from the CiviCRM application. How do I export this information?

Comment: It is good if you can show what research you did before asking on SE. Starting with the documentation is a good step usually

Comment: What specifically do you want to export?  If you just want basic contact data (eg name, address, phone etc) then Search Contacts > Export works as described in the answers below.  If you want data like their contributions, activities, memberships, event participations etc -  that needs a different answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a search of contacts exporting contacts will be one of the options in the action menu? So step by step:

1. Navigate to Search>Find Contacts
2. Click on the Search button (use one of the filters if required)
3. Select all contacts (or just a few if you want to)
4. If you click on the **Actions** box just under the selection you will see **export contacts** as one of the possible actions.

You will have this possibility with each search form. You can also use one of the reports and click the 'export to csv' button.

Does that help?

There is also an extension that you might find useful: https://civicrm.org/extensions/export-excel (only if you have issues opening the exports in Excel)

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, it's hard to answer your question definitively.  There are a number of ways to export contact data.

However, the most common way is covered in the documentation under [Exporting Your Contacts](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/exporting-your-contacts/).  There's much more detail there, but the general principle can be summed up in the first three steps:

- Search for contacts. Carry out a search based on your desired criteria using one of the available search tools, e.g. Quick search, Find Contacts, Advanced search, Search Builder, or a custom search.
- Select contacts you wish to export. Select all records, or choose individual records for export using the check-boxes to the left of each record.
- From the - actions - dropdown menu, choose Export Contacts. This takes you to the export wizard.